# TimeSpan formatting using Total

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Is it possible to format a c# `TimeSpan` with `TotalHours` using `string.Format`?

I have looked through the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx), but I can not find anything.

I know, I can do it through a converter (I am using Xamarin `XAML`), but as I hope my app will go worldwide, I do not like, that it is the way to go.

***Example***

In ViewModel something like this is set

```
public TimeSpan CurrentOutput {get; set;}

public ViewModel()
{
   CurrentOutput = new TimeSpan(1,2,3,4,5);
}
```

And in the `XAML` code something like this

```
<Label Text="{Binding CurrentOutput, StringFormat='{}{0:<total_hours>:mm}'}" />
```

Comment: Of course you can format `TotalHours`, it's just a regular `double`. It all depends on what format you expect. `TotalHours` doesn't have any time-specific formatters because it's not a time-based type. There is an extensive list of formats (can be used in ToString and string.Format) at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx). It might help to know what you are trying to do, so if you could include a [mcve] you might even get an answer :)

Comment: what output do you expected ?

Comment: Are you asking how to specify total hours in a format string, without accessing the `TotalHours` property? BTW, whether you use a converter or format in code doesn't affect globalization

Comment: As you can see in the currently added example, I want `<total_hours>` to be used in a format string without accessing the `TotalHours` property. <br />
I know, it does not affect globalization, but it could be nice, if you could format it like `string.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Now);`

Comment: Not sure why you insist not accessing TotalHours.

Comment: There is no custom format specified for `TimeSpan` which will show `TotalHours`, so you will have to bind to the property yourself. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then I will have to create a Converter, as I needs both total hours and minutes in the same label

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you insist not accessing TotalHours but in case you change your mind...

```
<Label Text = "{Binding CurrentOutput.TotalHours, StringFormat='{0:0}'}" />
```

or just

```
<Label Text = "{Binding CurrentOutput.TotalHours}" />
```

Comment: It is not using `TotalHours` but only hours, so if I have more than 23 hours, this will not show it